# React didn't return updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create custom hook which returns it's state

it looks like

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(
    Object.keys(steps).findIndex(stepKey => history.location.pathname.includes(stepKey))
);

const updateActiveStep = () => {
    setActiveStep(Object.keys(steps).findIndex(stepKey => history.location.pathname.includes(stepKey)));
};

return {
    activeStep }
```

inside this hook i call updateActive step function. But active step didn't change in my component

```
const { steps, activeStep, nextStep, setStep } = useSteps();
console.log(activeStep); //always initial
```

where i gone wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting `stepKey` from? Have you checked whether that changes?

Comment: @Agney yeah, because activeStep inside my hook properly changes. Problem in my component which doesn't getting that new value